# Setter issue while converting JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, json, mapping, backend

I'm trying to convert below simple JSON to Java Object using com.fasterxml.jackson.core. I have problem with bonusAmount field setter method.

JSON:

```
{"amount":332.5, "bonusamount":3, "action":"Spend"}
```

Java class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GameRequest {

@JsonProperty("amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@JsonProperty("bonusamount")
private BigDecimal bonusAmount;

@JsonProperty("action")
private String action;

.....

public BigDecimal getBonusAmount() {
    return bonusAmount;
}

public void setBonusAmount(BigDecimal bonusAmount) {
    this.bonusAmount = bonusAmount;
}
```

Value of bonusAmount field is NULL when I try to use it but if I change name of setter method from setBonusAmount to setBonusamount then it works. Can someone tell me why??

Comment: Cause in your `JSON` property you have `bonusamount`. when converting to setter function its add `set` int the front and capitalize the first letter

Comment: I also tried with bonusAmount for JSON property and still NULL value

Comment: change both in `JSON` and `JAVA`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have renamed your field using `@JsonProperty("bonusamount")` that means Jackson searches for a method named `setBonusamount` (first char toUpperCase, rest stays the same)

Comment: yes, that's because the property in the json is named "bonusamount" it would work if you rename your field to "bonusamount" (and the setters accordingly) and remove `@JsonProperty`